# ruby: Getting SIGBUS on a simple IO.popen loop?

Tags: ruby, signals

I have a simple 'system()' like utility method I use to run other programs, and the important bit is here:

```
        File.open(args[:out], 'w') { |outfile|
          IO.popen(cmd) { |cmdout|
            while (line = cmdout.gets)
              outfile.puts line
            end
          }
        }
```

I am using this to (amongst other things) run a very long-running perl script (on the order of a week long run).

Somehow I am occasionally having my ruby script catch a SIGBUS error, though the perl script is still left running in the background after the ruby script dies.

The error from ruby is: "Exited with exit code 135"
(and 135-128 is 7, which is a SIGBUS)

I found a core file in the directory and sure enough it's from the ruby interpreter and the backtrace looks like it's not in my code at all at this point:

```
Python Exception exceptions.ImportError No module named traceback:                                                       
#0  0x0000155555545d4c in _Unwind_IteratePhdrCallback () at ../.././libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde-dip.c:406                      
#1  0x0000155553fbdb1c in dl_iterate_phdr () from /lib64/libc.so.6                                                       
#2  0x0000155555546ba1 in _Unwind_Find_FDE (pc=0x15553b5bf2e1, bases=bases@entry=0x706578)                               
    at ../.././libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde-dip.c:469              
#3  0x00001555555433b3 in uw_frame_state_for () at ../.././libgcc/unwind-dw2.c:1257                                      
#4  0x00001555555451f9 in _Unwind_Backtrace (trace=0x155553f95aa0 <backtrace_helper>, trace_argument=0x706780)           
    at ../.././libgcc/unwind.inc:302                        
#5  0x0000155553f95c16 in backtrace () from /lib64/libc.so.6                                                             
#6  0x0000155555019677 in rb_print_backtrace () at ../vm_dump.c:755                                                      
#7  rb_vm_bugreport (ctx=0x706b80) at ../vm_dump.c:941      
#8  0x0000155554e6b533 in rb_bug_for_fatal_signal (default_sighandler=0x0, sig=7, ctx=0x706b80,                          
    fmt=0x15555505a5b3 "Bus Error at %p") at ../error.c:658 
#9  0x0000155554f85d3a in sigbus (sig=7, info=0x706cb0, ctx=0x706b80) at ../signal.c:932                                 
#10 <signal handler called>   
#11 0x000015555533b931 in do_lookup_x () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2                                                
#12 0x000015555533c20f in _dl_lookup_symbol_x () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2                                        
#13 0x0000155555340f1e in _dl_fixup () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2                                                  
#14 0x0000155555348bea in _dl_runtime_resolve_xsavec () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2                                 
#15 0x000015553b5bf2e2 in ?? ()                             
#16 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Any thoughts on why I'd get a SIGBUS in ruby?  This seems like it would have to be a ruby bug or a bug in one of my libraries, but near as I can tell it's only running the above ruby code when the SIGBUS occurs.

(Or perhaps an explanation of what happens to ruby when it actually gets a SIGBUS - and is there a way I can see what my ruby code is doing?)

Comment: If I intentionally send a SIGBUS to a ruby script, then it gives me Ruby backtrace info, but somehow I'm not seeing this - perhaps because the ruby script is alrady trying to exit??

Comment: It's calling `rb_bug_for_fatal_signal`. Makes it smell like a Ruby bug. Could be failed GC on your long-running script, but I am just guessing. Have you tried the latest Ruby version? If yes, you might try to just create an issue on the Ruby bug tracker.

Comment: I'll try a newer version - but at work we only have access to 3.0.0 at the highest end (and aren't supposed to install a new ruby without it being checked by the sw team first), so I'm limited to 3.0 for now.  I tried searching ruby issues for a BUS bug, and I see that SIGBUS is actually used for GC which is suspicious, but not seeing any bugs on older rubies.  Any suggestions for what to watch for to figure out what the bug is?

Comment: Have you put the Riby process into a Screen session or similar, so that you can see if it actually prints a stack trace when it crashes? Usually, even if Ruby fails due to a core dump, it should output a technical crash dump before it fails. That's what I would try first. I.e. check the output of the crashed process.

Comment: Sadly it does not dump anything else.  :-(